# Pass parameter to other Python file

Tags: python, file, parameters, flask, global-variables

I'm using Flask and Python. For one route, I'm doing the following

```
@app.route('/volumes/<volumeid>')
def volumeSpecific(volumeid):
   if volumeid not in volumesList:
    abort(404)
else:
    import retrieveVolumes
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The problem is, in my `retrieveVolumes` file, I need the specific `volumeid` parameter.

In the `retrieveVolumes` file this is where I use it

`current_snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(filters={'volume-id': volumeId})`

I tried making a global variable for the parameter `volumeid`, but that didn't work.

How do I pass the parameter, to the other file?

Comment: why not make `retrieve_volumes(volumeid)` into a method in the file, then do `from volumes import retrieve_volumes`?

Comment: @corvid Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: to be quite honest, I am not entirely sure what you are attempting to do. From the looks of it, I discern you are trying to fetch some unique volume from a database? If so, why not do the following, using `flask-sqlalchemy` ? https://gist.github.com/DarkCrowz/2a7913fef6a340aecffc

Answer (score 0):

Modules are not meant to be used as functions. At least add a `main` function to your retrieveVolumes module, then you can call it with `main(volumeId=volumeId)` or similar.

Comment: I'm confused. How do I access the volumeId from retrieveVolumes?

Comment: Create a function in retrieveVolumes, and after you import retrieveVolumes, then call that function with your value for volumeId.